# Firestore Database structure issue updating multiple documents in transaction

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, database-design, architecture

I have a database with a collection of "properties" and a collection of "calendars".

On each calendar document there is a field: "properties" which is an object of key: bool's.

```
properties: {
    XYZ: true,
    ABC: true,
}
```

Then I also have a field on each property with the calendarID.

```
calendarID: XYZ
```

This way I can see which calendar the property belongs to and which properties the calendar has.

When I update a calendar and add a property, I also update the property and add the calendar key. I'm doing this in a transaction. All good.

My issue comes when I go to remove a property from the calendar.

I can't save the bool field on the calendar to false, because when I update the calendar it would update the property, however the property could be active on a different calendar.

Example:

1. Add property XYZ to calendar A = XYZ: true
2. Remove property XYZ from calendar A = XYZ: false
3. Add property XYZ to calendar B = XYZ: true
4. Update calendar A randomly = FAIL as this would remove the calendarID from property XYZ because it thinks its false.

So I think saving the key: bool isn't the correct way.

How do I properly update both the calendar and the property in a transaction?

Should I use an array? If I did this, then wouldn't I need to pass in a list of deleted properties into the transaction?

Thank you for your input.